# Java exception when running a Minecraft Modded Server .bat

Tags: java, minecraft, minecraft-forge

I downloaded the server folder from the minecraft technic page for the 1.12.2 pack and upon running the LaunchServer.bat I get the following error:

```
A problem occurred running the Server launcher.java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:64)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
        at net.minecraftforge.fml.relauncher.ServerLaunchWrapper.run(ServerLaunchWrapper.java:70)
        at net.minecraftforge.fml.relauncher.ServerLaunchWrapper.main(ServerLaunchWrapper.java:34)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: class jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader cannot be cast to class java.net.URLClassLoader (jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader and java.net.URLClassLoader are in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')
        at net.minecraft.launchwrapper.Launch.<init>(Launch.java:34)
        at net.minecraft.launchwrapper.Launch.main(Launch.java:28)
        ... 6 more*
```

My `java -version` outputs:

```
java -version

java version "15.0.1" 2020-10-20

Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 15.0.1+9-18)

Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 15.0.1+9-18, mixed mode, sharing)
```

For environment variables:

My `JAVA_HOME` is set to `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-15.0.1`

My Path contains `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-15.0.1\bin`

What I've tried:
I looked at the .bat file and changed it to the line recommended by minecraft.net. Also had a friend who is experienced with running servers take a look and he said the files and the lines for the batch file looked fine. So I figured that it was an issue with my java and how it is installed. After doing some research I deleted java from my computer and reinstalled jdk 15 (the latest at the time of this post), jdk 8 (because some forums mentioned that some servers only support 8), and the latest jre that my computer prompted me to download (jre1.8.0_271). I also noticed that I was supposed to have a JAVA_HOME variable in environment variables so I manually entered that as well as Path as is copied above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modded Minecraft 1.12.2 only supports Java 8. The error you got is because you tried to run it with Java 15. Change it to use Java 8 instead.